# Is there a way to find the textmate scope from within my VSCode extension language functions?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am authoring a VSCode language extension using the `typescript-language-features`.  As part of that extension, I'd like to register a hover provider (using [`vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerHoverProvider)) that offers syntax help.

I suspect that the best way to select context-relative suggestions is to evaluate the current [textmate scope](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) of the text under the cursor.  Is that scope available to my providers?  If so, can you suggest a method for accessing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, your assumption is wrong. The textmate-scope (as you call it) is a simple, regex-based assignment of a scope ID for certain letter combinations. It doesn't help at all for things like code hints or code completion.

Instead you have to write your own parser for the language you want to support, which in turn can give you precise symbol information for a given position. This can then be used to derive code hints and other information.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Secondly, thanks for the great [ANTLR extension for VS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4).  It's been a big help to me.

I implemented my parser in ANTLR, and my syntax highlighting using the textmate grammar format.

Would you recommend using ANTLR to generate a typescript (or similarly convenient) `typescript-language-features` extension for code hints and etc?  Or is this likely to require an external language server?

Comment: My extension is entirely written in Typescript, so yes, definitely recommended.