# Textmate scopes in custom hover-provider for vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a custom language extension for my own script language. I've written a tmlanguage file to tokenize my script and do custom highlighting. I created a hover-provider that currently only shows the word that is hovered for testing the provider itself. I want to react on the textmate scopes of the current position in this hover, like the vs code Developer tool "Inspect Editor Token and Scopes" does.
At the end I want to react to one particular scope whose value I want to read and show a corresponding image of this value in the hover.

Fore example a line in my script could look like:
`setImage(dic_1/dic_2/testImg)`
Now I want to show the image that correlates with the path in the brackets if I hover over it.

I tried to find something in the documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages) if there is something that would help me but couldn't see anything related.
I tried to ask ChatGPT for help after he suggested "possible internal and not public available methods" it suggested to create a custom hover provider with the help of the library "oniguruma" and tokenize the document again.
However, this feels a bit like an overkill. If vscode has a internal tool that does return the textmate scopes I would guess there is a easy way to access those tokens.

I found this thread ([Is there a way to find the textmate scope from within my VSCode extension language functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72171334/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-textmate-scope-from-within-my-vscode-extension-langua)) but I don't rally understand why I need to write another parser.

Is there any way to access this textmate scopes in a hover-provider?

Comment: how difficult is it to look around the cursor position and determine if you are inside the `setImage()` call?

Comment: You are right. Maybe I was thinking to complicated. However, it would have been nice to do it without string comparison and have access to textmate scopes for other use-cases. A  more generic approach.